"Cannot open driver.tmh" error in visual studio KMDF project
The title says it all, I get the following error "Cannot open driver.tmh" after creating a new KMDF project in visual studio 2022.
I have tried turning WPP tracing on but it didn't help. I have looked for other solutions online but only found some posts in Chinese and the bit about enabling WPP tracing. I could use some help. I have already installed the windows driver kit, spectre mitigations and already tried to repair visual studio.
